# Can most things be done in code that can be done in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For example, I'd like to do something similar to what you see below, but in code behind. I see tons of example using XAML, but nothing for doing the same thing in C#. So my guess is no. Thanks.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="455">
        <Span FontSize="20">2</Span>
        <Span BaselineAlignment="TextTop" FontSize="14">1/2</Span>

        <Span FontSize="20"> + </Span>

        <Span FontSize="20">3</Span>
        <Span BaselineAlignment="TextTop" FontSize="14">3/4</Span>

        <Span FontSize="20"> = </Span>

        <Span FontSize="20">6</Span>
        <Span BaselineAlignment="TextTop" FontSize="14">1/4</Span>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why on earth do you want to NOT do this the easy way?

Comment: I'm new to WPF and don't yet understand how to use the code above with variables. Say for the 6 1/4 part, if that value was calculated on the C# side.

Comment: AFAIK, anything done in XAML can be done in C# code.  It may not be ideal, it may even be difficult to figure out how, but it _should_ be possible. At the very least, I haven't seen anything that couldn't be. _Yet._

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: It's true, XAML code maps to CLR constructs so anything you can do in XAML, you can do in code. Obviously, this means the reverse isn't true (everything in code, you can't necessarily do in XAML).

Comment: Petzolds book 'Applicstion = Code + Markup' only introduce Xaml in the last section of the book. Before that, everything is done in code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do WPF application require the use of XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766330/do-wpf-application-require-the-use-of-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, *almost anything* that can be done in Xaml can be done in C# as well, <del>since Xaml is converted into C# when building (look for `*.g.cs` files)</del>. You mostly can just use the same classes you specify in the Xaml, with a few additions that Xaml handles automatically for you. In this case you can do:

```
var textblock = new TextBlock();
textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run("2") {FontSize = 20});
textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run("1/2") {FontSize = 14, BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.TextTop});
```

Comment: Thanks ceykooo. I'm going to look into using bindings to do the same thing as above as it really seems to be the way to go. But in the mean time, your reply does answer my immediate question.

Comment: Great, bindings are definitely much easier to deal with once you get used to them. The general principle is you should always avoid code-behind unless it's *far* more work to implement what you want in Xaml. Additionally, doing things in Xaml allows for far more code reusability (ie, attached behaviors, converters, styles), and its typically harder to make mistakes in declarative code.

Comment: "Xaml is converted into C# when building" not true, those generated files are just supplementary to provide for example named fields for elements in XAML. The XAML itself is only if ever converted to BAML. "anything that can be done in Xaml can be done in C# as well" is not true either, there are some limits.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misconception. Do you have any resources you can direct me to regarding the limitations of C# compared to XAML?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this XAML output can be done through C# code as well

**Pseudocode**

Create a [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) object

Create a [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) object. Set it's [TextWrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping.aspx) Property to Wrap and [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) to 455.

Create multiple objects of [Span](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.aspx). Set the FontSize and other properties (text, BaseAllighnemt) according to your needs.

Add[span](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.aspx) objects to [Textblock.Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property

Add Textblock to stackpanel

Thats it

Answer (score 1):

The XAML code is parsed and objects are created that correspond to the markup, so you can always do the same by creating the objects directly.

So, you just create Span objects and set the right properties, and add them as children to a TextBlock object.

Answer (score 1):

For the XAML you posted, believe me, the XAML is much more readable and compact. For you to do this in code, you would have to instantiate the `Window` and the `StackPanel`, add the `StackPanel` to the `Window`, give the `Window` its title, height, and width properties, etc, etc. You're already looking at about six lines to do just that, it gets even uglier when you start instantiating the `TextBlock` and setting the `Span`.

You can absolutely use WPF without the XAML, although I'm not really sure why you would ever want to. An example of a WPF program that does just that can be found [here](http://www.tbiro.com/Hello-WPF-Without-XAML.htm). In fact, the reverse of your question is true. Everything you can do in XAML, you can do in C#, but not everything you can do in C#, you can do in XAML. This is because XAML maps directly do Common Runtime Language classes, properties, events, etc. but a mapping doesn't exist between every class and a piece of XAML code.

Long story short, XAML is much more maintainable and easier to edit than pure code, and requires simpler tools (an XML editor) to work with and is thus preferable to using pure code.

Comment: Your description sure makes it sound easier, but being new to WPF, I don't yet understand how to use the code above with variables. Say for the 6 1/4 part, if that value was calculated on the C# side.

Comment: @JimDel: I started programming UIs with Java's Swing, so they often looked a lot like what it seems you're trying to create, but believe me, it's much easier to maintain XAML and XML based UIs. Having once learned XAML, I would suggest looking at the "WPF Unleashed" book as once I got that, I didn't really ever need another resource. The link between the code and the XAML is done via bindings, and it's also pretty easy to find tutorials on that.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I'll look that book up.